# Excel: find if value is within dates and mark "x"

Tags: excel, sorting, date, report

I have 50 itens spread throughout 400 days, so I want to create a new spreadsheet to see these itens spread in time. The desired result whould contain an "x" at each cell confirming its presence and "empty" when result don't match.
For exemple:

Original information (2 columns, 7.000 lines):

```
..Date..........|..Item  
01.jan.2016.....|.AAA  
01.jan.2016.....|.BBB  
01.jan.2016.....|.ZZZ  
15.feb.2016.....|.AAA  
16.feb.2016.....|.ZZZ
```

Desired spreadsheet (50 lines, 400 columns):

```
Item...|.01.jan.2016.....|.Date2....|.Date3....|.Date4...  
AAA:...|.X...............|.X........|..........|.............
BBB:...|.X...............|..........|..........|.............
CCC:...|.................|..........|..........|.............
ZZZ:...|.X...............|..........|.X........|.............
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF($A$2=INDEX($L$2:$L$17,MATCH(B$1,$K$2:$K$17,0),0),"X","")
```

where `$A$2` is the item cell and `B$1` is the date cell.

Please check the attached image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. Seems incorrect due to dates column (K), where it should repeat several items at the same day (AAA, BBB, CCC and all other could happen at the same day).

Answer (score 1):

@Fabr83:

Yes, this formula will work only if the date is not repeated...

Here is the formula to get the X value even if the date is repeated:

(make sure to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to get those curly brackets around the formula in the formula bar).

[image]

Comment: {=IFERROR(IF($A2=INDEX($F$2:$F$8,MATCH(1,(B$1=$E$2:$E$8)*(A2=$F$2:$F$8),0),0),"X",""),"")}